# Not able to generate liquibase changelog

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to execute command on my command prompt:

`liquibase --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver  --classpath=E:\mysqljar\mysql.jar  --changeLogFile=E:\1.xml  --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc" --username=root --password=root generateChangeLog`

But I am getting this error:

> Liquibase Update Failed: Empty result set, expected one row
>   SEVERE 24/9/13 6:29 PM:liquibase: Empty result set, expected one row
>   liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error getting jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc view with liquibase.statement.core.GetViewDefinitionStatement@53330681
>           at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.readView(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:168)
>           at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.readViews(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:304)
>           at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.createSnapshot(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:241)
>           at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(DatabaseSnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:69)
>           at liquibase.diff.Diff.compare(Diff.java:63)
>           at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:145)
>           at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:760)
>           at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:134)
>   Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Empty result set, expected one row
>           at liquibase.util.JdbcUtils.requiredSingleResult(JdbcUtils.java:124)
>           at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:159)
>           at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:167)
>           at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:163)
>           at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.getViewDefinition(AbstractDatabase.java:748)
>           at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.readView(JdbcDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.java:166)
>           ... 7 more

Could anyone help me to interpret this?

Comment: It appears to be having a problem getting a view definition. There have been significant improvements to the snapshot/generateChangeLog process in liquibase 3.x. Could you upgrade to 3.0.5+ and see if that helps?

Comment: I tried using 3.0.5+, but getting same error

Comment: If you add --logLevel=DEBUG it should output the SQL being ran right before the error, what query is it making?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

My fix:
There needs to be an entry in the `database change log lock` table; it needs to have `id=1`, `locked=false` and the rest of the values set to `null`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm getting the same error also using MySQL and tried v3.0.0 and 3.0.5 of liquibase.  The error was the same when I tried to do a **migrate** as well as a **generateChangeLog**.

./liquibase --logLevel=debug --changeLogFile=./db.changelog-test-v0.1.xml --username=abc --password=abc99 --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" migrate

FYI, here is the select statement that it had trouble executing for the 'migrate' command:

**select view_definition from information_schema.views where table_name='patient_info' and table_schema='test'**

The information_schema.views table is empty.